# Acropol fibreglass turned yellow on flat roof, what causes this?

Tags: roof

We recently had roofers add 2 layers of back acropol fibreglass on our kitchen flat roof to help improve it's lifespan.  A month has passed and the coating has substantially discoloured and started to crack (see attached photo):

[image: Photo of discoloured flat roof]

What's could cause the coating to turn this colour so rapidly?  We have had heavy rainfall and a cold winter if that's of note.

Comment: Is that the roofing material, or mud from atmospheric dust in a low spot?

Comment: It could very well be from mud, water does pool there when it rains.  What concerns me is that we didn't see this before the new coat